# Custom error pages in Reporting Services 2008

Tags: reporting-services, error-handling

I'd like to re-brand (and send error emails) for all of the SSRS default error pages (picture below) when you access reports via /ReportServer/.  I'm already handling the ASP OnError event and *some* of the default SSRS errors appear to catch their own exceptions and then render this page cancel the response all before the OnError event is ever fired.

Any idea on how I can get a handle into SSRS to brand all error pages?

[image: Reporting Services Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't when using the visual aspects of SSRS. You can if you consume the reports directly via SOAP and the web service.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and came up with the following solution. It's prone to breaking things if Microsoft changes this particular method. The following code would be added to the header of the page to make sure it runs after the ReportViewer javascript is loaded, but before an instance of the RSClientController is created.

```
// This replaces a method in the ReportViewer javascript. If Microsoft updates 
// this particular method, it may cause problems, but that is unlikely to 
// happen.The purpose of this is to redirect the user to the error page when 
// an error occurs. The ReportViewer.ReportError event is not (always?) raised 
// for Remote Async reports
function OnReportFrameLoaded() {
    this.m_reportLoaded = true;
    this.ShowWaitFrame(false);

    if (this.IsAsync)
    {
        if(this.m_reportObject == null)
        {
            window.location = 
                '<%= HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath %>/Error.aspx';
        }
        else
        {
            this.m_reportObject.OnFrameVisible();
        }
    }
}
RSClientController.prototype.OnReportFrameLoaded = OnReportFrameLoaded;
```

The original code from the Microsoft ReportViewer script file (inside the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, 8.0.0.0, .Net Framework 3.5 SP1) is:

```
function OnReportFrameLoaded()
{
    this.m_reportLoaded = true;
    this.ShowWaitFrame(false);

    if (this.IsAsync && this.m_reportObject != null)
        this.m_reportObject.OnFrameVisible();
}
RSClientController.prototype.OnReportFrameLoaded = OnReportFrameLoaded;
```

Answer (score 1):

i created this solution for SSRS2005 and 2008. below is 2008r2 version

in reportviewer.aspx, add right before `</form>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rptDivString=document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl10_NonReportContent').innerHTML;
//alert( rptDivString );
var numPermError = rptDivString.search(/permissions/i);
if (numPermError>0)
{
var docTitle = document.title;
var reportName = docTitle.substr(0,docTitle.length-16);
alert('Reporting Services permissions error in report: ' +  reportName );
}
</script>
```