# How can I customise error messages in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, message

I have SSRS Report being accessed from a Report Server. Is there any way I can give an error message of my own, if my report fails to open there?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any way to capture RS errors if you are using SSRS report manager. On the other hand, if you are using the report viewer control, you may have a higher chance of capturing the errors. The same goes if you use custom dataset extension for report rendering.

Answer (score 0):

1. Browse to Report Manager folder. For SSRS 2005, its typical location
   is

   > DRIVE:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.x\Reporting
   >   Services\ReportManager, where x is the instance; for SSRS 2008 and
   >   SSRS 2008 R2, DRIVE:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
   >   Server\MSRS10.SSRS\Reporting Services\ReportManager.
2. Make a copy of the existing Web.config as backup
3. Open Web.config in a text editor, or in Visual Studio to get
   Intellisense support
4. Under the section, locate the  section
5. Modify the existing section, or insert a new one, with
   the appropriate settings
6. Restart the Report Server

Custom error messages for SSRS 2008 have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188373/custom-error-pages-in-reporting-services-2008)