# how to treat/handle an exception and display a custom error message on Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, exception, reporting-services

Fellow developers,

I'm creating a report to be seen directly by the clients, so I need to ensure maximum user-friendliness. When the user types an invalid date string the report throws a `rsReportParameterTypeMismatch` and displays an error messages like this:

```
An error occurred during local reoprt processing
Query Execution Failed for data set 'myDataSet'
```

I want to replace this cryptic (for the final user) message for a more friendly custom message. How or where can I write them? How do I intercept the exception? I don't need anything too complex, just changing the words, perhaps colors and sizes would suffice.

I thank thee in advance for thy willingness to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [Custom error pages in Reporting Services 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188373/custom-error-pages-in-reporting-services-2008)