# Handling SSRS error RsProcessingAborted while cube is processing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, custom-error-handling

I have a specific requirement in which I need the latest cube refresh date in my report dataset and show it on my report. However while running this report simultaneously when the cube is processing I get a error message saying rsProcessingAborted: Query execution failed for DataSet "DataSetName" etc. My question is can I hide this error and show any custom message when user tries to open the report while the cube is down for processing or not available?

I know there is custom code option in SSRS report properties, is it possible to write a custom try catch block to handle these error type properly from SSRS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188373/custom-error-pages-in-reporting-services-2008 - try to handle it in dataset  query level.

Comment: i dont think it can be handled at the query level, as the error occurs while accessing the cube from SSRS.

Comment: Have you tried using the `IsError` function around your MDX query?